# Inline form not working correctly

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get an inline form out of bootstrap using the class `form-inline`. However, I'm encountering some unexpected behavior and I'm using exactly the same code as listed on the Boostrap official page.

This is what I get:

[image: I dont want this]

The code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="new-value">Enter new value: </label>
        <input type="text" id="new-value" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            Public: <input type="checkbox" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

When I remove the `form-control` class from the text box I get the wanted result, but I don't have the cool text box then:

[image: I wanna be cool]

I'm aware of the warning from bootstrap:

> This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.

But this is on a large screen and the form width is 1160px.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code.
Hope this is what you wanted!

> **HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="new-value">Enter new value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="new-value" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label> Public:
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Check this for the working model http://www.bootply.com/ZWGwdEcnva

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is the code I get, once .net compiles the helper. The only difference is `<form action="/" class="form-inline" method="post">`, which makes zero difference.
I've also tried nesting the text input inside the label, but that yields no result.

Comment: I dont know `.net`. I put each items in a `<div class="form-group">` So that each form-group align center